# Where is the most performant place to set up my programmatically created view?

Tags: ios

I have seen it done in `viewDidLoad` , `init` ,`viewWillAppear`, and `loadView`. I have heard a variety of answers and figured a definitive answer would be best!

Answer (score 2):

Most view initialization should be done in `viewDidLoad`. `viewWillAppear` isn't appropriate because it can be called many times in a view controller's life.

Layout should be done in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` but the actual creation of subviews belongs in `viewDidLoad`.

`loadView` is only used if you want the view controller's root view to be something other than a simple, empty `UIView`.

Comment: so for viewwillLayoutSubviews, is that were i would instantiate my views and set the frame then add them to the subview in viewDidLoad?

Comment: You create the subview and add them to the parent view once in `viewDidLoad`. You set their frames in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. This is called to initially layout the view as well as whenever the view size changes (rotation, in-call status bar appears, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

There's no *performance* difference (all of these are just normal method calls...).

The only actual difference is that `viewWillAppear:` is called whenever the view becomes visible (not only once), so it's not a good place to put initialization code into. By the way, you have two other options too: the `init` (or designated `initWithWhatever:`) and `viewDidLoad` methods.

Answer (score 0):

The designated initializer. If you subclass UIViewController, you must call the super implementation of this
  method, even if you aren't using a NIB.  (As a convenience, the default init method will do this for you,
  and specify nil for both of this methods arguments.) In the specified NIB, the File's Owner proxy should
  have its class set to your view controller subclass, with the view outlet connected to the main view. If you
  invoke this method with a nil nib name, then this class' -loadView method will attempt to load a NIB whose
  name is the same as your view controller's class. If no such NIB in fact exists then you must either call
  -setView: before -view is invoked, or override the -loadView method to set up your views programatically.

The text above is from the Apple Documentation. According to it, you should do that in the "loadView" method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view before the viewDidLoad and add the view in the viewDidLoad, layout the view on ViewWillLayout and load data (if have) on viewWillApper.
You can see the example bellow (import UIKit)

```
class MyView: UIViewController {

// create the view
let myview: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .orange
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Add the view
    self.view.addSubview(myview)
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    // create the constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.myview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        self.myview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
        self.myview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
        self.myview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    // You can implement extra data to your view here
}
```

}